# Focus of the element is wrong during selenium webdriver automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My scenario:
1. Click on the Forgot username and password
2. Input wrong user ID and press tab. 
3. Modal dialog appears with wrong ID text.
4. Accept the alert

Expected behavior:
Focus should be on the user ID text box.

Actual behavior:
In IE11- Through automation and manual the focus is on the userID text box.
In Chrome - Manual execution the focus is on the user ID textbox. But through automation the focus is on 'Ok' button(some other button in the page).

Why there is such a difference in behavior?
Selenium WebDriver-2.53.0
Chrome-49.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JavascriptExecutor` as below:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementid').focus();");
```

Hope it will help you :)